# Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab

Sorry I'm new to matlab and was wondering if anyone could help me,

I am writing abit of code,

```
    M= inital_conditions
time_vals = start_time:delta_t:end_time;
for iidx = 1 : length(time_vals)
  i = time_vals(iidx);

  new_conc = old_conc +  delta_t*EQN(old_conc);
  k(:,iidx)= new_conc;
  old_conc=new_conc;
end
```

I keep getting the error Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts.

I used the size() and realise that k(:,iddx ) is 1 X 9 and new_conc is 1 x 8. Could anyone suggest a way I could balance the 2 sides?

Thanks

EQN script

```
function output= EQN(M)

M = [90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90];
k1=1;
k2=1;
k3=1;
k4=1;
k5=1;
k6=1;
k7=1;
k8=1;
k9=1;
k10=1;
k11=1;
k12=1;
k13=1;
k14=1;
%k15=1;


output(1,1) = k14-k5*M(1)*M(2)-k4*M(1)*M(4)%-k1*M(5)*M(6)));
output(2,1) = -k5*M(1)*M(2);
output(3,1) = k5*M(1)*M(2);
output(4,1) = k13*M(14)-k3*M(9)*M(4)-k3*M(9)*M(4);
output(5,1) = k4*M(1)*M(4)- k1*M(5)*M(6);
output(6,1) = k10-k1*M(5)*M(6);
output(7,1) = k1*M(5)*M(6)-k2*M(7);
output(8,1) = k2*M(7)-k14*M(8);
output(9,1) = k11-k3*M(9)*M(4);
output(10,1) = k3*M(9)*M(4);
output(11,1) = 0;
output(12,1) = k6*M(10)*M(11)-k7*M(12);
output(13,1) = k7*M(12)-k12*M(13);
output(14,1) = k12*M(13)-k13*M(14);
output(15,1) = k12*M(13);
```

Comment: You need to make `k` be `8 x 9`

Comment: Based on the code you've provided now though, it looks like `new_conc` should have 15 elements, no? Be sure to clear `k` (`clear k`) before your loop to make sure that old data isn't interfering

Comment: when i use whos it states that new_conc is 15 X 15, howvever i seen on other questions stating that you should use size() and its coming up as 1 8

Comment: But in your question you said "I used the size() and realise that k(:,iddx ) is 1 X 9 and new_conc is 1 x 8. "

Comment: when i use whos it states that new_conc is 15 X 15, howvever i seen on other questions stating that you should use size() and its coming up as 1 8

Comment: There is no way that the two can yield different results.

Comment: whos   new_conc               15x15             1800  double              
  old_conc                1x15              120  double              
  start_time              1x1                 8  double              
  t                       1x15              120  double              
  time_vals               1x81              648  double              

>> size new_conc

ans =

     1     8 this is the command window display. sorry I am new to this

Comment: Right, but you said the output of `size` was different.

Comment: You should do `size(new_conc)`, not `size new_conc` (which gives you the size of the string "new_conc").

Comment: i apologise, you are right new_conc is 15x15

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your main problem is that you are the victim of unexpected [automatic implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), something added in MATLAB R2016b. Consider this example:

```
>> a = 1:10;      % Row vector, 1-by-10
>> b = (1:10).';  % Column vector, 10-by-1
>> c = a+b

c =

     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11
     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17
     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
```

Notice that the result **isn't** a ten-element vector of the element-wise sums of `a` and `b`. When your inputs are different (but [*compatible*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html)) sizes, MATLAB automatically replicates the necessary dimensions so they match. In previous versions, this would simply throw an error telling you that a row vector and column vector can't be added due to their different sizes.

The fix? Make sure your input to `EQN` (which currently appears to be a row vector, `old_conc`) is the same size as your output (which is currently a column vector). Adding `old_conc` (a 1-by-15 vector) to the output of `EQN` (a 15-by-1 vector) makes your result `new_conc` into a 15-by-15 matrix. **You must be very careful to check that your arrays have matching sizes in newer versions of MATLAB if you want to avoid implicit expansion!**

...You also have an additional problem that you're using the [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function wrong. If you want the size of a variable `new_conc`, it's `size(new_conc)`. If you type `size new_conc` you are getting the size of the command-line argument string "new_conc", which is a 1-by-8 character array.